# Set active for adding step by step in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want it to default to : ***Additional Info*** , instead of : ***Personal details***

I have searched, but can't find any documentation for this. Please help me. Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/bt5dhqtf/98/

```
<div id="app">
<div>
        <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete" 
                      shape="square"
                      color="#3498db">
            <tab-content title="Personal details"
                         icon="ti-user">
              My first tab content
            </tab-content>
            <tab-content title="Additional Info"
                         icon="ti-settings">
              My second tab content
            </tab-content>
            <tab-content title="Last step"
                         icon="ti-check">
              Yuhuuu! This seems pretty damn simple
            </tab-content>
        </form-wizard>
 </div>
</div>
```

//

```
Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 methods: {
  onComplete: function(){
      alert('Yay. Done!');
   }
  }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the start-index prop for the default selected tab

`:start-index="1"`

check the below example

https://jsfiddle.net/1z9mfp7y/1/